# How to tell if a git repo is a mirror?

Tags: git

I'm trying to get my head around git mirroring. Given a working copy, how do I determine whether it is a mirror (or is mirroring) another repository?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are in fact *two kinds* of mirrors, as noted in [the `git remote` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html):

> When a fetch mirror is created with `--mirror=fetch`, the refs will
>    not be stored in the *refs/remotes/* namespace, but rather everything
>    in *refs/* on the remote will be directly mirrored into *refs/* in the
>    local repository. This option only makes sense in bare
>    repositories, because a fetch would overwrite any local commits.
>
> When a push mirror is created with `--mirror=push`, then `git push`
>    will always behave as if `--mirror` was passed.

A fetch mirror (which is what you get if you use `git clone --mirror`) is detectable by its two key settings, `core.bare` and its `fetch` line:

```
$ git remote add --mirror=fetch rfetch ssh://upstream.host/path/to/repo.git
$ git config --get-all remote.rfetch.fetch
+refs/*:refs/*
$
```

Detecting a push mirror is simpler:

```
$ git remote add --mirror=push rpush ssh://upstream.host/path/to/repo.git
$ git config --get --bool remote.rpush.mirror
true
```

If a specific `remote.remote.fetch` is set to `+refs/*:refs/*` but the repository does *not* have `core.bare` set to `true` (which you can discover using `git config --get --bool core.bare` or `git rev-parse --is-bare-repository`; both do the same thing), you have a confused repository (such as the one I made to illustrate the above :-) ).  If there is more than one `remote.remote` section, and any of them have `fetch=+refs/*:refs/*`, you have a weird-at-best repository (in theory a fetch mirror with multiple remotes could work as a sort of union repository, but all remotes would need to use different references, e.g., only one could have a `master` branch).  You can find all the remotes using `git config --get-regexp` or `git config --list` and extracting items that match regular expression `^remote\.`.  Here `awk` is actually perhaps the most suitable processor if writing scripts:

```
$ git config --list | awk -F. '$1 == "remote" { if (!r[$2]++) print $2 }'
rfetch
rpush
$
```

Having obtained a list of remotes, you can then probe each one for its mirror-ness as either fetch or push mirror.  If any is a fetch mirror, `core.bare` should be `true`.

Answer (score 7):

try:

```
git config --list | grep remote

remote.origin.url=<git remote url>
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/*:refs/*
remote.origin.mirror=true
```

I don't understand the subtleties listed above, but this worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Git uses a peer to peer architecture.  A git repository that is a mirror will appear and act just like it's source.  To tell them apart, you could look in the '.git/config' file, because config files are not pushed, but it won't explicitly indicate it is a mirror.